# Select and convert column values in SQL Server result set

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's suppose i have a table called 'customer' in SQL Server 2008, with this result set :

```
select * from customer

cu_id  cu_status
1      O
2      C
3      O
```

The 'cu_status' column is a code and i want to convert it to its correspondent value : 'O' is 'Open' and 'C' is 'Closed'. So my desired result set would be :

```
cu_id  cu_status
1      Open
2      Closed
3      Open
```

Is there a way to do it only with a SELECT command ?

Thanks !

Comment: Yes, it can be done, as the answers show. However, it is generally accepted that **formatting** of output (which includes, for example, date and currency formatting, but also this kind of translation) should be done in the UI layer rather than in the SQL.

Comment: If you have more than those two values you might consider using a lookup table. If you have only those two values then you should consider using a bit datatype instead. Something like IsOpen.

Comment: @SeanLange Actually it's just an example, i have several values but it's inside an app server in a multi-tier app, not in the database and i was requested to create a view in the DB. Wrong approach i know, but too late to change now ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. The simpler one would be using a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT cu_id,
       CASE cu_Status
          WHEN 'O' THEN 'Open'
          WHEN 'C' THEN 'Closed'
       END cu_status
FROM dbo.customer;
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked, is there a way to select the column using CASE and an "AS" statement ? Like 'select cu_status as "Status" .

Comment: ?, just replace `END cu_status` with `END SomeAliasHere`

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do the following:

```
SELECT CU_ID,
    CASE WHEN CU_STATUS = 'O' THEN 
        'Open'
    ELSE 
        'Closed'
    END AS CU_STATUS
FROM CUSTOMER
```